# Sass is breaking Rspec (uninitialized constant Sass::Util (NameError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sass, autotest

When I try to run rspec or autotest I keep getting the error:

```
/Users/Craig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sass-3.1.0.alpha.249/lib/sass/plugin.rb:35:in `<module:Plugin>': uninitialized constant Sass::Util (NameError)
```

After I remove sass from my Gemfile the specs run fine.

Is there a way to tell rspec to ignore a gem? Or what do I have to do get rspec/autotest to run? And why does rspec depend on the Gemfile to run anyways? rake spec works fine, but running rspec /file/path or autotest doesn't.

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "3.0.5"

gem "grape"

gem "mongoid", "2.0.0.rc.7"
gem "bson_ext", "1.2.4"
gem "mongoid_search"
gem "will_paginate", :git => "https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git", :branch => "rails3"
gem "bluecloth", "2.0.0"

gem "devise", :git => "https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
gem "oauth2"
gem "warden_oauth"
gem "devise_invitable", :git => "https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git"

gem "simple_form", :git => "https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git"
gem "haml", :git => "https://github.com/nex3/haml.git"
gem "compass", ">= 0.10.6"
gem "sass"
gem "fog"
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave", :git => "https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.git"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "quasi", "0.1.0", :path => "./vendor/gems/quasi-0.1.0/"
gem "mongoid_slug", :require => "mongoid/slug", :git => "https://github.com/papercavalier/mongoid-slug.git"
gem "faker"
gem "jammit", :git => "https://github.com/caifara/jammit.git"
gem "sanitize"
gem "right_aws", :git => "https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws.git"

group :development do
  gem "yard", "0.6.4"
  gem "yard-dm", "0.1.1"
  gem "hpricot"
  gem "ruby_parser"
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem "rails3-generators",    :git => "https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators.git"
  gem "haml-rails",           :git => "https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails.git"
  gem "hirb"
  gem "heroku_san", "1.0.8"
  gem "right_http_connection", :git => "https://github.com/rightscale/right_http_connection.git"
  gem "barista", :platforms => :ruby
  gem "therubyracer", :platforms => :ruby
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails",          :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git"
  gem "whenever", :require => false
  gem "pathy"
end

group :test do
  gem "nokogiri" ,  "~> 1.4.4.0"
  gem "jasmine"
  gem "rspec",                :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec.git"
  gem "rspec-core",           :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git"
  gem "rspec-expectations",   :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git"
  gem "rspec-mocks",          :git => "https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git"
  gem "spork", "~> 0.9.0.rc", :git => "https://github.com/timcharper/spork.git"
  gem "steak", ">=1.0",       :git => "https://github.com/cavalle/steak.git"
  gem "capybara",             :git => "https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git"
  gem "fabrication",          :git => "https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication.git"
end

group :production do
  gem "dalli"
end
```

Here's what spits out when I run gem list

```
aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.5)
actionpack (3.0.5)
activemodel (3.0.5)
activerecord (3.0.5)
activeresource (3.0.5)
activesupport (3.0.5)
addressable (2.2.4)
algorithms (0.3.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.0.9)
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-fsevent (0.2.5)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
barista (1.0.0)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
bluecloth (2.0.0)
bson (1.2.4)
bson_ext (1.2.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
capybara (0.4.1.2)
celerity (0.8.8)
childprocess (0.1.7)
chunky_png (1.1.0)
closure-compiler (1.0.0)
coffee-script (2.1.3)
coffee-script-source (1.0.1)
columnize (0.3.2)
compass (0.10.6)
configuration (1.2.0)
culerity (0.2.15)
dalli (1.0.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
excon (0.5.6)
faker (0.9.5)
faraday (0.5.7)
ffi (0.6.3)
fog (0.6.0)
formatador (0.0.16)
grape (0.1.3)
haml (3.0.25)
heroku (1.18.0)
heroku_san (1.0.8)
hirb (0.4.0)
hpricot (0.8.4)
i18n (0.5.0)
iobuffer (1.0.0)
jasmine (1.0.1.1)
jquery-rails (0.2.7)
json (1.5.1)
json_pure (1.5.1)
launchy (0.3.7)
linecache19 (0.5.11)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
mongo (1.2.4)
mongoid (2.0.0.rc.7)
mongoid_search (0.1.2)
multi_json (0.0.5)
multi_xml (0.2.1)
multipart-post (1.1.0)
net-ssh (2.1.0)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
oauth (0.4.4)
oauth2 (0.1.1)
orm_adapter (0.0.4)
pathy (0.0.4)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-jsonp (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.5)
railties (3.0.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rest-client (1.6.1)
rev (0.3.2)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.24)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby-fsevent (0.2.1)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby_core_source (0.1.4)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
rubystats (0.2.3)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sanitize (2.0.0)
sass (3.1.0.alpha.249, 3.1.0.alpha.221)
selenium-client (1.2.18)
selenium-rc (2.3.1)
selenium-webdriver (0.1.3)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
spork (0.8.4)
stackdeck (0.2.0)
stringex (1.2.0)
sys-uname (0.8.5)
therubyracer (0.8.1)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.24)
warden (1.0.3)
warden_oauth (0.1.1)
watchr (0.7)
whenever (0.6.6)
xpath (0.1.3)
yard (0.6.4)
yard-dm (0.1.1)
yui-compressor (0.9.4)
ZenTest (4.5.0)
```

Comment: rspec doesn't depend on the Gemfile but rspec-rails does. It loads the Rails environment which uses bundler to require the correctly versioned gems, hence the Gemfile. If you are having problems with Sass in your specs, it'll probably crop up elsewhere. Seems like a good time to figure out the origin of the issue.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I added edited my original post with my gemfile.

Comment: I use rspec with haml/sass all the time, without any errors. Does your `rails console` start, or `rails server` without that error? I am assuming your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: rails s and rails c run without any errors. I posted a gem list as well if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was related, but this post came up top when googling for that error message.

I was getting the following exception after upgrading to Rails 3.1:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/../sass/plugin/compiler.rb:29: uninitialized constant Sass::Util (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/../sass/plugin.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/sass/rails3_shim.rb:15
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/sass/rails3_shim.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/../sass.rb:19
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/version.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `try_sass'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/sass.rb:6
```

which was caused because I had an old compass.rb file in config/initializer.

Deleting that file solved my problem